# SQL order of execution for correlated subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have the following **Personnel table**:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+
| name    | dept_nbr | job_title   |
+---------+----------+-------------+
| Michael | 14       | Programmer  |
| Kumar   | 14       | Programmer  |
| Dave    | 14       | Programmer  |
| Jane    | 14       | Manager     |
| Carol   | 37       | Programmer  |
| Joe     | 37       | Programmer  |
| John    | 59       | CEO         |
+---------+----------+-------------+
```

**Problem**: Find all dept_nbr's (departments) that have fewer than 3 programmers.

**Working query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT dept_nbr
  FROM Personnel AS P1
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(P2.dept_nbr)
          FROM Personnel AS P2
         WHERE P1.dept_nbr = P2.dept_nbr AND P2.job_title = 'Programmer') < 3;
```

**Result:**

37

59

**Notes:**

Department 14 is correctly not included as it has 3 programmers (3 is equal to but not fewer than 3).  Department 59 has zero programmers, and is also correctly included in the results.

**My question:**

When the above query executes, how does a generic SQL engine proceed?  From what I have read, SQL execution order is (roughly): From, Where, Group By, Having, and Select. So, is the following correct?

**1 -** The Outer Query passes each row of the Personnel table as P1 into the Inner query.

**2.a -** The Inner Query scans the entire Personnel table as P2, row by row, looking for rows that satisfy the condition "P1.dept_nbr = P2.dept_nbr AND P2.job_title = 'Programmer'".

**2.b –** Once the Inner Query is done with the entire table, it COUNTs the matching dept_nbr values and returns it to the Outer Query.

**3 –** In the Outer Query, if the count returned from the Inner Query satisfies the condition "WHERE (Inner Query Count Result) < 3", the corresponding dept_nbr for the P1 row is SELECTed.

**4 –** Following all rows processed by the Outer Query, the Outer Query does a DISTINCT on the results and displays the unique dept_nbr values.

Is my understanding above correct?  Specifically, does the outer query do the DISTINCT at the very end (step #4)?  It seems that in this way, the inner query does redundant scanning (for example, it processes dept_nbr = 14 four times, when it really has the answer in the first pass).

I tested the above query on sqlfiddle.com w/ MySQL 5.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the above query executes, how does a generic SQL engine proceed?
>   From what I have read, SQL execution order is (roughly): From, Where,
>   Group By, Having, and Select.

This statement is -- generally -- not correct.  SQL is *parsed* in the order that you describe.  However, the *execution* is determined by the optimizer and might have little to do with the original query.  Remember:  SQL is a descriptive language, not a procedural language.  It describes the result set, not the specific steps for calculating it.

That said, MySQL's execution plan is much closer to the query than most other databases (particularly more advanced databases with better optimizers).  And, almost any database is going to proceed in the steps you describe for this query.  The aggregation in the subquery limits the choices for optimization.

If you want to eliminate the redundancy, then do the `select distinct` *before* the filtering:

```
SELECT dept_nbr
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT dept_nbr FROM Personnel P1) P1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(P2.dept_nbr)
       FROM Personnel AS P2
       WHERE P1.dept_nbr = P2.dept_nbr AND P2.job_title = 'Programmer'
      ) < 3;
```

You can also do this more simply with just an aggregation:

```
select dept_nbr
from personnel
group by dept_nbr
having sum(job_title = 'Programmer') < 3;
```

Comment: Thank you for this invaluable and detailed answer.  I have tested your queries, both work.  I was not aware of the possibility of a "HAVING SUM" construct.  Thanks again.

Comment: In fact, I see that "HAVING SUM" is covered in your book, first reference on p. 88! http://imgur.com/a/eZBtg Very cool. :)

Answer (score 3):

Add `EXPLAIN` (or `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`) before your query and it should give you the explain plan which will detail exactly the steps in order of your query.  This is a very useful tool when trying to optimize queries.